# mp4 video not displaying in HTML

Tags: html, mp4

I want to make an mp4 video player in my HTML website.
I use this code in the body:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document></title>
    <body>
        <video width="400" controls>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I save it and refresh my website in the browser, there is an mp4 box but the video is not playing.

Comment: Is the video.mp4 in the same directory as this html file?

Comment: yes Ravi, it is in the same directory

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of your directory?

Comment: when i will upload screenshot, stackoverflow will block my account or delete question and i need a solution in small time, can you help? video.mp4 and index.html is in the same directory. have you any solution?

Comment: In your browser doe ctrl -shft-i and tell us the errors it shows. It probaly cant find the vid

Comment: 404 means the video is not there.. or somehow not accessible.

Comment: thanks Grumpy! but how i solve it, have you solution?

Comment: Add the error here, so we can tell you whats wrong. Check the spelling of the name, are there capitals in the name?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the value **muted** if you are using it in chrome as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attributes)

> In some browsers (e.g. Chrome 70.0) autoplay doesn't work if no muted attribute is present.

```
<video width="400" autoplay controls muted>
```

Comment: which browser are you using? if you share a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) we would see how you are working on that.